# Nativescript - Sidedrawer error(this._ios.setMainView is not a function)

Tags: nativescript

Suddently i have this problem, which is the error on the title of this question...i was trying to implement the radlistview and honnestly i really don´t know what i did, the complete error is this:

```
JavaScript error:
file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/ui-sidedrawer.js:263:34: JS ERROR TypeError: this._ios.setMainView is not a function. (In 'this._ios.setMainView(content)', 'this._ios.setMainView' is undefined)
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Regards

Comment: Which version of SideDrawer & RadListView plugins you are using?

Comment: Hello Manoj, the sidedrawer is: nativescript-ui-sidedrawer 5.0.0 and it says DEV in front....the listview is: nativescript-ui-listview 5.0.0.

Comment: When exactly you are getting this error?

Comment: When i start the app with sidekick...it installs the app on my iphone, but when it says is refreshing, it breaks!.

Comment: Are you using any starter template? Can you show us what you have in your Page ?

Comment: Yes i´m using the sidedrawer template...what page do you refer?

Comment: I was referring to whichever page (XML / HTML) file you have RadSideDrawer declared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184686/discussion-between-japa-and-manoj).